# Cloudinary uploade image : Request has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, api, file-upload, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload an image in an angular project using the following approach

1- service:

[image]

2- html:

[image]

3- ts:
[image]

but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

can anyone help me solving this error?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post the answer,
the problem was I forgot I'm using Interceptor that adds headers,
It's not allowed by "Cloudinary", so if anyone has the same problem don't forget to make an exception in the "Cloudinary" requests and not adding headers.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MDN has some really good documentation on CORS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

You'll basically be required to send an additional header with the request to abide by the CORS security protocol.

Here's a StackOverflow link explaining the protocol [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)